# Wrong graphic due the scale , tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hi i want to graphic the function: -2.5x^2+30x-50

if you search the equation in google:

[image]

but when i put it on latex:

[image]

The green curve is that equation and it is wrong

i use an escale: 1x10^{-3} is equal to 2 , just using the labels.

the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ %inner axis line style={-latex},
width=15cm,height=6cm,
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                xlabel={$t[s]$},ylabel={$v(t)[V]$},
                unit vector ratio*=2 1 1,
                xmin=-2,
                xmax=14,
                ymin=-5,
                ymax=5,
                xtick={2,4,6,8,10,12}, xticklabels={$1x10^{-3}$,$2x10^{-3}$,$3x10^{-3}$,$4x10^{-3}$,$5x10^{-3}$,$6x10^{-3}$},
                ytick={-2,2,4}, yticklabels={-20,20,40},
              ]


\draw[red!60,domain=0:2,samples=100,ultra thick]plot(\x,0.25*\x^2);
\draw[red!60,domain=0:2,ultra thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(2,1)(4,3)};



\draw[green!60,samples=100,ultra thick]plot(\x^2,-2.5*\x^2+30*\x-50);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks .

Comment: Please make your question's title more accurate to the issue at hand. (make it searchable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You scaling seems wrong but I have no idea what units you were trying to use, which is why I simply rescaled them to your intended `2 -> 1e-3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  /pgf/number format/sci generic={
    mantissa sep=\times,
    exponent={10^{#1}},
  }
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    tick scale binop=\times,
    scaled ticks=false,
    xlabel={$t[s]$},
    ylabel={$v(t)[V]$},
    xticklabel style={rotate=20},
    domain=0:6e-3,
    ]
    \addplot[red!60  ,samples=100,ultra thick] {0.25*(x*2e3)^2};
    \addplot[green!60,samples=100,ultra thick] {-2.5*(x*2e3)^2+30*(x*2e3)-50};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, i used that scale, because the original function was:
-10000000x^2 +60000x-50
But appear an error:  "Dimension too large"